# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using vite-react and exposing using --host

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, vite, mern

## Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using react vite through network.

[image]

When accessing the "http://localhost:5173/" it is working fine but when accessing "http://192.168.101.222:5173/" it is showing white blank screen and show following error in console.

[image]

I tried to install basicSsl package using "import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'" and added it to vite.config.js :

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        basicSsl(),]
})
```

but then "https://192.168.101.222:5173/" is working and the localhost is not working and showing following when opening in browser.

[image]

I am using Vite 4.1.1 . It was working previously, but not it is not working.Are there any additional steps or configurations that I might be missing?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue?